# what is the best way to search for the fist non empty string ? php

Tags: php, search, php-5.3

I have this variables :
$string1 , $string2 , $string3 .
I want to search for the first non empty string : 
I did this :

```
!empty($string1)?$string1 : !empty($string2) ? $string2 : !empty($string3) ? $string3 : "empty"
```

but the above code doesn't work ?

Comment: Don't you here the parentheses screaming :)? The ternary operator is left Associated.

Comment: I do hear them @Rizier123!

Comment: me too , but what should I do !

Comment: @david See the dupe there are answer which shows how to put the parentheses in the nested ternary operators

Comment: @david Look at my parentheses: `((!empty($string1)?$string1:!empty($string2)) ? $string2 : !empty($string3)) ? $string3 : "empty" ` That's how your ternary operator gets evaluated right now!

Comment: When variables are numbered like this, then you're looking at a situation where an array is probably more appropriate

Comment: @Rizier123 yes yes thank you ! now  there are more parentheses screaming :)

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you mark , this what I will do !